# SQL: Insert newly created column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following table:

```
create table Finance
(
       [Product] int
       ,[Timestamp] datetime
       ,[Price] numeric(16, 4)
)

INSERT INTO Finance([Product], [Timestamp], [Price])
       VALUES
              (5678, '20080101 12:00:00', 12.34)
             ,(5678, '20080101 12:01:00', NULL)
             ,(5678, '20080101 12:02:00', NULL)
             ,(5678, '20080101 12:03:00', 23.45)
             ,(5678, '20080101 12:04:00', NULL)
             ,(5679, '20080101 13:04:00', NULL)
             ,(5679, '20080101 13:05:00', 30.35)
             ,(5679, '20080101 13:06:00', NULL)
```

and the following query returns desired output:

```
SELECT ISNULL(A.Price, B.Price) N_Price -- A.Product, A.Timestamp, A.Price, 
FROM Finance A
OUTER APPLY (   SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM Finance 
            WHERE Product = A.Product AND Timestamp < A.Timestamp
            AND Price IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY Product, Timestamp DESC) B
```

And I'd like to insert column N_Price returned by query into original Finance table. Is there any simple and fast way, how to do that?

Comment: Instead of inserting the column ,i would go with a view

Comment: That's I was wondering also, but I need to insert column.

Comment: Is this one time insert ?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't make a column and add the data in a single statement. You 'll have to add a column by something like alter table Finance add Price2 numeric(16,4) and then update.

Comment: Yes, one time insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for one time update

```
 alter table finance add n_price numeric(16,1)


update a
set n_price=ISNULL(A.Price, B.Price)
from finance a
outer apply
(
SELECT TOP 1 price
            FROM Finance 
            WHERE Product = A.Product AND Timestamp < A.Timestamp
            AND Price IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY Product, Timestamp DESC) B
```